# Dagger2 выдает ошибку приведения гд что не так?

Tags: java, android, dagger2

Хочу получить Receiver . делаю следующие шаги но прога падает

```
public class MvpApp  extends Application{

    private ApplicationComponent mApplicationComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mApplicationComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this)).build();
        mApplicationComponent.inject(this);
    }

    public ApplicationComponent getmApplicationComponent() {
        return mApplicationComponent;
    }
}
```

вот модуль

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final Application mApplication;

  public ApplicationModule(Application mApplication){
        this.mApplication = mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    @ApplicationContext
    Context provideContext() {
        return mApplication;
    }

    @Provides
    Application provideApplication() {
        return mApplication;
    }



    @Provides
    BluetoothConnectionStateRepository provideBluetoothConnectionStateRepository(BluetoothConnectionStateModel bluetoothConnectionStateModel){
      return new BluetoothConnectionStateRepositoryImpl(bluetoothConnectionStateModel);
    }


    @Provides
    BluetoothConnectionStateModel provideBluetoothConnectionStateModel(){
      return new BluetoothConnectionStateModel();
    }


  @Provides
  BluetoothConnectionStateReceiver provideBluetoothConnectionStateReceiver(){
    return new BluetoothConnectionStateReceiver();
  }


}
```

компонент

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(MvpApp app);

    void inject(BluetoothConnectionStateReceiver bluetoothConnectionStateReceiver);


    @ApplicationContext
    Context context();

    Application application();


    BluetoothConnectionStateRepository repository();

    BluetoothConnectionStateModel model();

    BluetoothConnectionStateReceiver receiver();
}
```

Вот и cсам Receiver падает там где делаетсся ((MvpApp)context).getmApplicationComponent().inject(this);
пишет не могу привести тип

```
public class BluetoothConnectionStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    @Inject
    BluetoothConnectionStateRepository mBluetoothConnectionStateRepository;


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ((MvpApp)context).getmApplicationComponent().inject(this);
        String action = intent.getAction();

        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // When discovery finds a device
        if (action.equals(mBluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)) {
            final int state = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, mBluetoothAdapter.ERROR);
            switch(state){
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF:
                    mBluetoothConnectionStateRepository.changeConnectionState(false);
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_OFF:
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON:
                 mBluetoothConnectionStateRepository.changeConnectionState(true);
                    break;
                case BluetoothAdapter.STATE_TURNING_ON:
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не каждый контекст `==` Application.

Сначала необходимо из контекста получить application context, а потом уже приводить к Application.

```
((MvpApp)context.getApplicationContext()).getmApplicationComponent().inject(this);
```